# How to Invoke this linq query?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, delegates

Suppose i have a method that return a dictionary as below :

```
private Dictionary<string, int> GetWorktypeDictionaryList()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, int>()
                   {
                       {"Select",-1},{"New MSC",1},{"Expansion",2},{"Migration",3},{"Upgrade",4},{"Relocation",5},{"Feature",6}

                   };
    }
```

now in main method i want to add dictionary key in lower case with previous dictionary value.For these purpose i use Action delegate. code are below :

```
Dictionary<string,int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            Action<KeyValuePair<string, int>> action =
                act => dict.Add(act.Key.ToLower(), act.Value);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> pair in GetWorktypeDictionaryList())
            {
                action(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(pair.Key,pair.Value));
            }
```

but i want to implement these 3 lines of code  in 2 lines like below.

```
Dictionary<string,int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
GetWorktypeDictionaryList().ToList().ForEach(act => dict.Add(act.Key.ToLower(), act.Value));//Here is the problem how to invoke Action.
```

but i couldn't  invoke Action in these scenario . Please Some of my advanced programmer friends help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `ToDictionary()`:

```
dict = GetWorktypeDictionaryList()
           .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key.ToLower(), kvp => kvp.Value);
```

I'm not sure how your `Action` comes in to play when you've embedded it in the second example.

Comment: Nice,Meet my jobs.Thanks Stanley.But can you tell me is it possible in last way that i tried.Just for increasing knowledge nothing else.

Comment: Action comes only trying it other way nothing else.